# NPE while executing jetty websocket servlet on GAE

Tags: websocket, jetty, chat

am working a chat app using jetty WebSocketServlet. But when i am executing that application, eclipse console displaying null pointer exception same as in the url [Jetty 8.1.9.v20130131 Web Socket issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14707694/jetty-8-1-9-v20130131-web-socket-issues).Even though am using jetty jars version 8.1.10 still am facing the error.

can anyone help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The test webapp, on the distribution, has a websocket example chat. Does that test webapp work for you?

Comment: How are you running the Jetty?

Comment: A full stacktrace of your error in 8.1.10 would be useful.

Comment: i have included jetty jars in build path of eclipse & build app using in GAE.Then executing GAE project thats all.am getting error NPE in console.

Comment: GAE (Google App Engine) does not support Websocket. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114902/how-can-i-run-a-websocket-server-on-top-of-gae

Comment: For that matter, GAE is written against Jetty 6 (under the org.mortbay.jetty namespace), and will require a fundamental update to at least Jetty 7 in order to support WebSocket.